# If $\phi^n$ belongs to $H^2(\mathbb D)$ for each $n\geq 1$, then does it imply $\phi$ belongs to $H^\infty(\mathbb D)?$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hardy-spaces

Consider $H^2(\mathbb D),$ the Hardy space over the unit disk. We know that if $\phi\in H^\infty(\mathbb D),$ the space of bounded holomorphic functions in the unit disk, then $\phi^n$  belongs to $H^2(\mathbb D)$ for each $n\geq1$ where $\phi^n(z)=(\phi(z))^n$.

Now we ask a converse question. Suppose $\phi$ is a function in $H^2(\mathbb D)$ such that $\phi^n$ is also in $H^2(\mathbb D)$ for each $n.$
Then does it imply that $\phi$ belongs to $H^\infty(\mathbb D)$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If $\{\phi^n\}$ are uniformly bounded in $H^2(\mathbb D),$ then using weak compactness, it follows that $\phi$ is necessarily bounded with sup norm less or equal to 1.

Comment: That is correct, but how to show that $\{\phi^n\}$ are uniformly bounded in $H^2(\mathbb D)?$